# Duda sobre replicación de base de datos

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Hola tengo una duda acerca de si se puede configurar lo siguiente en MySQL / MariaDB

Yo quiero tener 2 servidores de bases de datos que estén sincronizados. Estos serán acccesibles mediante un balanceador de carga. Lo que quiero es que ambos servidores estén totalmente sincronizados, de forma que si en el servidor 1 se crea una base de datos, automáticamente también se cree en el servidor 2. Si en el servidor 2 se insertan algunos registros, que esos registros se inserten automáticamente también en el servidor 1.
Quiero que ambos tengan la misma información independientemente de que un cliente acceda al servidor 1 o servidor 2

Hay alguna forma de hacer esto ?
Gracias

Comment: Puedes tener un raid espejo el cual se duplique la informacion

Comment: Pues puede ser buena idea. Pero así creo que solo podría hacer la replicación de un lado. Por ejemplo del servidor 1 al servidor 2, pero no tambien al reves

Comment: Sí hay modos de sincronización. Pero lo que no entiendo es si un servidor es MySQL y otro MariaDB, o si te vale cualquiera de las opciones

Comment: En principio queria que los 2 servidores fueran MySQL

Comment: Yo creo que al trabajar con un clúster si que se puede.

Comment: @Adrián te recomiendo el uso de [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol) para este tipos de preguntas ya que SO es creo que no lo permite porque esta basada en opiniones y en el chat te ayudan mejor